# Twig - Dynamic array key

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Currently working on a tool built on Symfony. I am iterating over an array of configuration settings. The thing I want to achieve seemed simple enough:

I am trying to obtain a certain value. One of the keys has to be dynamic though. Below is a working example without the key being dynamic.

```
{% set id = tmod_config.content_1.id %}
```

("content_1" being the key in question)

The number at the end of the key has to be dynamic. I have tried a couple of things but wasn't able to achieve this. Up to this point I have access to the dynamic value, it just needs to be turned into a functioning key.

Any suggestions?

**Question solved! Check the answers**

Comment: What's the source for the dynamic part of the key?

Comment: @Yoshi It's a parameter that was passed with the rendering of the template. Anyway, I have managed to solve the problem just now. Thanks for thinking along!

Comment: Np ;) But leave an answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 5):

As it is an array you could use either..

```
{% set id = tmod_config[content_1].id %}
```

or

```
{% set id = attribute(tmod_config, content_1).id %}
```

Comment: Soon after posting the question I tried a solution similar to your first solution. Got it working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem soon after posting it!

It can easily be done like this:

```
{% set id = tmod_config["content_" ~ contentId].id %}
```