# Displaying values from an array in Twig

Tags: php, twig

I have array in php:

```
Array ( [0] => pl [1] => en )
```

In dataArray i have:

```
pageTemplate.pageHeader.pageValue.dataArray.name_pl => "Polska"
pageTemplate.pageHeader.pageValue.dataArray.name_en => "Angielska"
```

and twig file

```
{% set items = pageTemplate.pageHeader.pageValue.availableLanguageVersions %}

{% for languageVersions in items %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="projectinput4">Name - {{ languageVersions|e|upper }}*</label>
                    <input required type="text" placeholder="Nazwa producenta" name="name_{{ languageVersions|e }}" maxlength="65" value="{{ pageTemplate.pageHeader.pageValue.dataArray.name_ }}{{ languageVersions|e }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I display the value of the dataArray in html / twig in value?
I would like that in name_pl be showed in value "Polska", and in name_en "Angielska".

In my current code i have in name_en => "en" and in name_pl "pl".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig - Dynamic array key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40975260/twig-dynamic-array-key)

Comment: in the set line try changing `.availableLanguageVersions` to `.dataArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first combine the name of the attribute, then access it with the [attribute twig function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html#attribute), as example:

```
{% set my_key = 'name_' ~ k %}

{{ attribute(dataArray, my_key) }}
```

See this runnning [twig fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/aylqz4)